# Collatz sequence without return statement

Tags: python, collatz

This is from the book titled "Automate the Boring Stuff with Python".
It requires the reader to:

a) Use only one parameter

b) If number is even, print and return number // 2

c) if number is odd, print and return 3 * number + 1

d) The function should keep getting called until the function returns the 
value 1.

What I wrote works, but I didn't use the "return" command, so is it correct?

```
def collatz():  
    print('Please enter a number: ')
    number = int(input())
    while number != 1:
        if (number % 2)==0: 
            number  = number / 2
            print(number)
            continue
        else:
            number = 3*number + 1
            print(number)
            continue
        break
collatz()
```

Answer (score 1):

You have all the right pieces, but it looks like requirements a) and d) have not been met. A minor refactor - pull out the `input` and `while` - should get you there:

```
def collatz(number):  # a) use one parameter
    if number % 2:
        next_num = 3 * number + 1
    else:
        next_num = number // 2
    print(next_num)
    return next_num


def run():
    number = int(input('Please enter a number: '))
    while number != 1:
        number = collatz(number)  # d) call the function repeatedly


run()
```

e.g.

```
>>> run()
Please enter a number: 3
10
5
16
8
4
2
1

>>> run()
Please enter a number: 9
28
14
7
22
11
34
17
52
26
13
40
20
10
5
16
8
4
2
1
```